# Error updating list when looping in Python

Tags: python, loops, pymupdf

Why is the list "spans" never being updated? I cannot figure out why the code gets stuck in an infinite loop.

PDF: https://www.sil.org/system/files/reapdata/62/99/18/62991811720566250411942290005522370655/40337_02.pdf

Sample of "blocks": https://jumpshare.com/s/y393JOBQJfIyE51Gkexn

```
import fitz

doc = fitz.open("cubeo/40337_02.pdf")
page = doc[3]

blocks = page.get_text("dict", flags = fitz.TEXTFLAGS_TEXT)["blocks"]
for block in blocks: 
    entries = []
    if len(block["lines"]) > 3: # ignora legendas e número de página
        for line in block["lines"]: 
            spans = []
            for span in line["spans"]:
                spans.append({"text": span["text"].replace("�", " "), "size": int(span["size"]), "font": span["font"]})

            # While there are spans left
            while True:
                # Delimits where an entry starts
                entry_first_position = None
                for i, span in enumerate(spans):
                    if span["font"] == "Sb&cuSILCharis-Bold":
                        entry_first_position = i
                        break
                if entry_first_position is not None:
                    # Delimits where an entry ends
                    entry_last_position = None
                    for i, span in enumerate(spans[entry_first_position:], start=entry_first_position):
                        if span["font"] == "Sb&cuSILCharis-Bold":
                            entry_last_position = i
                            break
                    if entry_last_position is not None:
                        # Whole entry is added as a list
                        append_list = spans[entry_first_position:entry_last_position]
                        entries.append(append_list)
                        spans = spans[:entry_first_position] + spans[entry_last_position:]
                    else:
                        break
                else:
                    break
             print(spans)
```

What I expect is that print(spans) outputs "[]". However, the code never gets to that point.

Comment: Are you asking about this line: `spans = spans[:entry_first_position] + spans[entry_last_position:]`? Maybe you're never getting into that `if` block. Add a `print` statement to tell if you get there.

Comment: @Barmar I get there, but the list stays the same.

Comment: Can you create a [mre]? It doesn't seem like the PDF is relevant, just extract a sample value of `blocks`.

Comment: @Barmar now I did

Comment: Can you put it in the question? Just a small excerpt of it, not the whole thing of course.

Comment: What exactly is this supposed to be doing? It looks like you're just trying to remove everything between each pair of `Sb&cuSILCharis-Bold`, is that correct?

Comment: @Barmar content between each pair of `Sb&cuSILCharis-Bold` is added to `entries`, then that content is removed from `spans`. When I print `spans` after  `spans[:entry_first_position] + spans[entry_last_position:]`, there is no change.

Comment: 7 layers of indentation generally indicates a code smell (badly written code) that can be simplified.  did the code really need to be indented that much ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i, span in enumerate(spans[entry_first_position:], start=entry_first_position):
```

is not skipping over the first match for `span["font"] == "Sb&cuSILCharis-Bold"`. So `entry_last_position == entry_first_position`, nothing gets removed, and you get stuck in an infinite loop. Change that to

```
for i, span in enumerate(spans[entry_first_position+1:], start=entry_first_position+1):
```

so it starts at the next position in the list to find the